# kubernetes PersistentVolume over google cloud storage bucket

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have created a persistent volume claim where I will store some ml model weights as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: models-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: model-storage-bucket
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

However this configuration will provision a disk on a compute engine, and it is a bit cumbersome to copy stuff there and to upload/update any data. Would be so much more convenient if I could create a `PersistentVolume` abstracting a google cloud storage bucket. However, I couldn't find anywhere including the google documentation a way to do this. I am baffled because I would expect this to be a very common use case. Anyone knows how I can do that?
I was expecting to find something along the lines of

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-volume
spec:
  storageBucketPersistentDisk:
    pdName: gs://my-gs-bucket
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/filestore-csi-driver#storage-class

Answer (score 1):

To mount cloud storage bucket you need to install [Google Cloud Storage driver](https://ofek.dev/csi-gcs/getting_started/) (**NOT** the persistent disk nor file store) on your cluster, create the StorageClass and then provision the bucket backed storage either dynamically or static; just as you would like using persistent disk or file store csi driver. Checkout the link for detailed steps.